# Fix container at bottom till window.pageYOffset is greater than original position of container

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am fixing the position of container `stickyDiv` at the bottom of viewport once user scrolls past top of `stickInDiv`, till its original position ( that I calculate from the top of document) is first revealed at the bottom of viewport. After that the container should remain at its original position. On scrolling up, it should again get fixed to the bottom of viewport once its original position hits the bottom of viewport.

**Current behaviour**: `stickyDiv` does not stay at its original position once its original position is reached at the bottom of viewport.

```js
window.onscroll = function() {
  scrollFunction();
};

function getTop(elem) {
  const box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

  const body = document.body;
  const docEl = document.documentElement;

  const scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docEl.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;

  const clientTop = docEl.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0;

  const top = box.top + scrollTop - clientTop;

  return Math.round(top)
}


const stickyDiv = document.getElementById('stickyDiv');
const stickyElemTopFromDocumentTop = getTop(stickyDiv);
const Height = stickyDiv.clientHeight; /* height of the sticky element */
const stickInDiv = document.getElementById('stickInDiv');
const stickInDivOffsetTop = stickInDiv.offsetTop;

function scrollFunction() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > stickyElemTopFromDocumentTop) {
    stickyDiv.classList.remove('sticky');
  } else if (window.pageYOffset > stickInDivOffsetTop) {
    stickyDiv.classList.add('sticky');
  } else {
    stickyDiv.classList.remove('sticky');
  }
}
```

```css
#contentAtTop {
  height: 100px;
  background-color: blue;
  opacity: 0.2;
  color: white;
}

#contentBeforeStickyDiv {
  height: 1200px;
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

#stickyDiv {
  color: white;
  background-color: grey;
  height: 40px;
}

#contentAfterStickyDiv {
  height: 400px;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.sticky {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="contentAtTop">Content At Top</div>
  <div id="stickInDiv">
    <div id="contentBeforeStickyDiv">Content Before Sticky Div</div>
    <div id="stickyDiv">Sticky Container</div>
    <div id="contentAfterStickyDiv">Content After Sticky Div</div>
  </div>
</body>
```